# How to allocate ION's memory of predefined heap type?

Tags: c, linux

I cannot find documentation about ION's allocator.
I don't know how to allocate contiguous memory of the selected heap type using ion.

I've tried to allocate memory using following code:

```
    struct ion_allocation_data arg_alloc;

    arg_alloc.len = len;
    arg_alloc.heap_mask = heap_mask;
    arg_alloc.flags = flags;
    arg_alloc.fd = 0;

    ret = ioctl(client, ION_IOC_ALLOC_V1, &arg_alloc);
```

I don't understand the logic, which value should be placed into **heap_mask** variable.

Comment: As I can see, this thread is dead. Can anyone give me advice about how to contact  Linux developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ION's driver contains ioctl's command "ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY" argument which may be used to get information about heaps (name, type, id, etc.), enabled on concrete platform.
Example of implementation was found on the following [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libion/ion.c):

```
int ion_query_heap_cnt(int fd, int* cnt) {
    int ret;
    struct ion_heap_query query;
    memset(&query, 0, sizeof(query));
    ret = ion_ioctl(fd, ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY, &query);
    if (ret < 0) return ret;
    *cnt = query.cnt;
    return ret;
}

int ion_query_get_heaps(int fd, int cnt, void* buffers) {
    int ret;
    struct ion_heap_query query = {
        .cnt = cnt, .heaps = (uintptr_t)buffers,
    };
    ret = ion_ioctl(fd, ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY, &query);
    return ret;
}
```

Example of use for this API is found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/linaro/hikey/+/refs/heads/master/gralloc/alloc_device.cpp):

```
static int find_ion_heap_id(int ion_client, char* name)
{
    int i, ret, cnt, heap_id = -1;
    struct ion_heap_data *data;
    ret = ion_query_heap_cnt(ion_client, &cnt);
    if (ret)
    {
        AERR("ion count query failed with %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    data = (struct ion_heap_data *)malloc(cnt * sizeof(*data));
    if (!data)
    {
        AERR("Error allocating data %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    ret = ion_query_get_heaps(ion_client, cnt, data);
    if (ret)
    {
        AERR("Error querying heaps from ion %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            struct ion_heap_data *dat = (struct ion_heap_data *)data;
            if (strcmp(dat[i].name, name) == 0) {
                heap_id = dat[i].heap_id;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i > cnt)
        {
            AERR("No System Heap Found amongst %d heaps\n", cnt);
            heap_id = -1;
        }
    }
    free(data);
    return heap_id;
}
```

That is how heap_id is obtained.
To get heap_mask we need to:

```
heap_mask = (1 << heap_id);
```